# Count of groups in impala SQL

Tags: sql, count, impala

My impala table is as below.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Abc     1       A       desc1
Abc     1       A       desc2 
Abc     1       A       desc3 
Abc     1       A       desc4
Abc     1       B       dwsc1
Abc     1       B       dwsc2
Xyz     1       A       desc1
```

I would like to find out the count of distinct column values in column3 for each combination of column1 and column2.

For example. For combination of Abc and 1 I have 2 values in column3 - A and B. For Xyz and 1 I have only one.

Expected output:

```
Column1 Column2 count(column3)
Abc     1       2     
Xyz     1       1
```

How to achieve this in impala ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use distinct count

```
select column1,column2, count(distinct column3)
from table
group by column1,column2
```